# Resetting stack with RNN lib

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

Cannot reset a stack with following use cases.

1. Let assume Screen A is a root, and navigate to Screen B,
   Then while navigating to Screen C, I want the stack to have A->C instead of A->B->C.
2. If a stack has A->B->C and I want to rest the stack with root screen as C.

Please help on this use cases

Comment: Can you include some of the code you have tried and/or any error messages you get?

Comment: For first use case I'm not seeing any methods in the Lib and for the second use case, I'm getting "Component ID already exists"

Answer (score 0):

1. This use case is not supported as removing an element from the middle of a stack is not a valid stack api. You probably want to show B in a **modal**, then push C into the stack contained in the modal. If you want to disallow the user from going back from C to B, then instead of push use `setStackRoot` with C.
2. use [setStackRoot](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/screen-api?id=setstackrootcomponentid-params) with C

Comment: Is it possible to set the sideMenu for a modal screen?